# How to make object bounce forever at same height

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics, pyglet

I am trying to make a ball bounce forever, at the same height always, as it would if no energy was lost in the bounce.

I don't know why, depending on what I do it bounces higher as time goes by, or it bounces lower with every jump. My expectation is that in every bounce it should always reach the same height, not higher or lower.

This is my code (the code is in pyglet, but it is really easy to read even if you don't know the library). Here, a square is dropped from the middle of the screen, marked by an arrow, and I expect the cube to bounce in the floor and go exactly to the original height when coming back:

```py
import pyglet


class Polygon(object):
    def __init__(self, vertices, color, velocity=0, acceleration=-600):
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.y_idx = 1
        self.num_vertices = int(len(self.vertices) // 2)
        self.colors = color * self.num_vertices
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.acceleration = acceleration
        self.bottom_edge = 0

    def draw(self):
        self.vertex_list = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(self.num_vertices,
                                                       ("v2f", self.vertices),
                                                       ("c3B", self.colors))
        self.vertex_list.draw(pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON)

    def move_by_offset(self, offset):
        for i in range(1, len(self.vertices), 2):
            self.vertices[i] += offset  # only modify y values

    def bounce(self, dt):
        if self.vertices[self.y_idx] < self.bottom_edge:
            self.velocity = abs(self.velocity)
            return True
        return False

    def update(self, dt):
        # move
        self.move_by_offset(self.velocity * dt)
        # check if bounce
        self.bounce(dt)
        # accelerate
        self.velocity += self.acceleration * dt


class GameWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, objects=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.objects = objects

    def update(self, dt):
        for obj in self.objects:
            obj.update(dt)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        for obj in self.objects:
            obj.draw()


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, w=400, h=400, title="My game", resizable=False):
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        objects = [
            # square
            Polygon(vertices=[w/2-20, h/2, w/2-20, h/2+40, w/2+20, h/2+40, w/2+20, h/2],
                    color=[0, 128, 32],  # green
                    velocity=0,
                    acceleration=-6000),
            # arrow, marks exactly how high the square should bounce
            Polygon(vertices=[w/2, h/2, w/2+40, h/2+20, w/2+30, h/2, w/2+40, h/2-20],
                    color=[255, 255, 0], # yellow
                    velocity=0,
                    acceleration=0)
        ]
        self.window = GameWindow(objects, self.w, self.h, title, resizable)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.window.update(dt)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game(resizable=False)
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1/120)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

I tried different update orders, like modifying speed according to acceleration before changing velocity after bounce, or even not accelerating at all after bounce (which seems to work the best) but still the bounce is not accurate and changes heights constantly:

```py
    def update2(self, dt):
        # move
        self.move_by_offset(self.velocity * dt)
        # accelerate
        self.velocity += self.acceleration * dt
        # check if bounce
        self.bounce(dt)

    def update3(self, dt):
        # move
        self.move_by_offset(self.velocity * dt)
        # check if bounce
        bounced = self.bounce(dt)
        if not bounced:
            # accelerate (only if no bounce happened)
            self.velocity += self.acceleration * dt
```

I even tried something more complex: creating 2 dt's, one before and one after bounce, and doing 2 acceleration updates, but this did not work either.

Can you guys help me? What is the way to program game physics for such a simple scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerical integration is hard!  Since you can easily solve the one-dimensional ballistic equation exactly, do so: compute

```
y1=y0+v0*dt+g*dt*dt/2
v1=v0+g*dt
```

This is the [velocity Verlet method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration) in the trivial case of a constant acceleration.  If `y1<0`, you can solve the quadratic equation to find out *when* it bounced and restart the integration from that point (with the velocity negated).

If you want to incorporate more complicated physics while still being numerically accurate, consider the **centering** of your velocity variable.  Better accuracy can be had by staggering it—defining it at points in time that are halfway between the points at which position is defined gives the similar [leapfrog method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration).

A very different approach for conservative forces is to define a total energy for the ball and move it according to how much of it must be kinetic based on its height.  Even then, you have to include the above correction with `dt*dt` to avoid numerical problems near the maximum altitude.

Answer (score 0):

There reason your equation not working is because your update function is missing the amount of position change that caused by acceleration. This should work.

```
import pyglet
import math

class Polygon(object):
    def __init__(self, vertices, color, velocity=0, acceleration=-600):
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.y_idx = 1
        self.num_vertices = int(len(self.vertices) // 2)
        self.colors = color * self.num_vertices
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.acceleration = acceleration
        self.bottom_edge = 0

    def draw(self):
        self.vertex_list = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(self.num_vertices,
                                                       ("v2f", self.vertices),
                                                       ("c3B", self.colors))
        self.vertex_list.draw(pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON)

    def move_by_offset(self, offset):
        for i in range(1, len(self.vertices), 2):
            self.vertices[i] += offset  # only modify y values

    def bounce(self, dt):
        if self.vertices[self.y_idx] < self.bottom_edge:
            self.velocity = abs(self.velocity)

            dropped_height = (self.velocity**2) / (-self.acceleration * 2) 
            drop_time = math.sqrt(2 * dropped_height / -self.acceleration)
            print("dropped height:", dropped_height)
            print("drop time:", drop_time) 

            return True
        return False

    def update(self, dt):
        # move
        move_by_velocity = self.velocity * dt
        move_by_acceleration = 1/2 * -self.acceleration * dt * dt
        self.move_by_offset(move_by_velocity + move_by_acceleration)
        # check if bounce
        self.bounce(dt)
        # accelerate
        self.velocity += self.acceleration * dt


class GameWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, objects=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.objects = objects

    def update(self, dt):
        for obj in self.objects:
            obj.update(dt)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        for obj in self.objects:
            obj.draw()


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, w=400, h=400, title="My game", resizable=False):
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        objects = [
            # square
            Polygon(vertices=[w/2-20, h/2, w/2-20, h/2+40, w/2+20, h/2+40, w/2+20, h/2],
                    color=[0, 128, 32],  # green
                    velocity=0,
                    acceleration=-6000),
            # arrow, marks exactly how high the square should bounce
            Polygon(vertices=[w/2, h/2, w/2+40, h/2+20, w/2+30, h/2, w/2+40, h/2-20],
                    color=[255, 255, 0], # yellow
                    velocity=0,
                    acceleration=0)
        ]
        self.window = GameWindow(objects, self.w, self.h, title, resizable)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.window.update(dt)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game(resizable=False)
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1/120)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: The square bounces forever at a similar height on your code, but they height it reaches varies slightly.

Comment: @someguy Well, I blame floating point numbers, or maybe someone could point if I made any mistake or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking, and I believe that an object will usually not achieve the same height even though the program is completely accurate. Because the bounce causes the object to take different positions on the way up than on the way down, at the top the object may appear lower, due to the fact that in the game loop only certain frames of the object's true motion are shown. These frames may not correlate to the ball's highest position.
Sorry this is so late, but here is my try in js. You can run this in the console of any webpage. Notice the total energy stays nearly the same, and probably would be more accurate without my sloppy coding.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="375" height="555"></canvas> <p id ="text"></p>'

var x = 200;
var y = 105.3;

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight-120


var g = .2
var ballRadius = 3;
var xsp = 0;
var ysp = 0;   
var iysp = 0; 
var p = 0;
var ip = 0;
var iy = 0;
var high = 200;
var a = 0
var b = 0
var fix = 0
var iter = 0

var fpms = 10

var gi = 0
var gii = 0
var brek = 100000000
var dt = 1
var smallt = 0
var mass = 1
var total = 0

function totale() {
    total = parseFloat(((mass*g*(500-y))+(.5*mass*(ysp*ysp))).toFixed(8))
}

function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0,0,200,105.3-ballRadius);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0085DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0,500,200,100);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0085DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
    if (iter==brek) {
        clearInterval(mainLoop)
        return;
    }
    iysp = ysp
    iy = y
    ysp = parseFloat((ysp + g*dt).toFixed(8))
    y = parseFloat((y + ((ysp+iysp)/2)*dt).toFixed(8))
    totale()
    if (y > 500) {
        ysp = iysp
        y = iy
        ysp = Math.sqrt(iysp*iysp+(2*g*(500-y)))
        b=ysp
        smallt = 1-((ysp-iysp)/g)
        ysp = ysp*-1+((g*dt)*smallt)
        y = parseFloat((500 + ((ysp+b*-1)/2)*dt*smallt).toFixed(8))
    }
        
    
    if (y < iy) {
        high = y
    }
    iter ++
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = '__y speed= '+ysp+'<br>'+'__highest y value= '+high+'<br>'+'__y pos'+(y)+'<br>'+'__smallt= '+(smallt)+'<br>'+'__iter= '+iter+'__total e= '+total
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
    drawBall();
    
}
mainLoop = setInterval(draw,fpms)
```